# ¿Cómo ejecutar un método que se encuentra en otro proyecto pero en mi misma solución?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

tengo una solución que contiene dos proyectos y quiero traer un método que esta en el segundo proyecto es decir en el proyecto uno quiero que se ejecute un método del proyecto2, así estoy intentando traerlo pero me da error creo que tengo que agregar alguna referencia o algo así

```
        [HttpGet("/getCities")]
        public async Task<List<CitiesResponse>> Get1()
        {
            //Prin es el metodo que quiero que se ejecute y que esta en el segundo proyecto  
            Print();
            return await _repository1.getCities();
        }
```

y este es el método que quiero traer :

```
        public ActionResult Print()
        {
            return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { nombre = "Pedrito" }) {FileName = "Test.pdf"};
        }
```

de antemano gracias

Comment: Ese print esta dentro de una clase no? tenes que referenciar la clase (haciendo el using) y luego generar un objeto de esa clase...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sigue los siguientes pasos para ello:**

1. Click derecho sobre tu proyecto principal; Agregar y Referencia de proyecto.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Activa los proyectos que desees agregar.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Con esto ya solo puedes importar lo que necesites:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]